# Is it allowed to use '/' within the value of the id of a html-element

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Hi,
I'm struggeling with the jQuery UI Tabs and the needed ids.
Let me give you an example:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#messages/pn1">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages/pn2">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="messages/pn1"></div>
  <div id="messages/pn2"></div>
</div>
```

Now when I click on the second tab i get an exception like "jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier."
Isn't it allowed to user slashes in ids?

Comment: Ok solved. That was was i needed:
If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \\. For example, if you have an element with id="foo.bar", you can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar"). From http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

Sorry.  HTML Spec indicates otherwise.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/types.html#type-name

Answer (score 1):

It is not allowed. Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)